# What kind of Cloud do I need?

Tags: delphi, azure, cloud

There's a program MetaTrader4 that can run scripts.
My script reading data from text files (up to 3 gb) and analyse them. 
It's like Excel vba script analysing sheet's data.
Billions of iterations. Results of calculating stored in another txt file (up to few GBs)

1. Is it possible to run many instances of MetaTrader4 using cloud (Azure?)
2. If no I can recode script to Delphi application is that possible for Azure or other cloud service?

If so how can I do that? I have a trial in Azure but don't know where to start.

Comment: Azure Cloud has a lots of services. if you are using "Virtual Machine", it is just like your local machine, you can config it to run what ever you want (you can get both Windows and Linux machine from Azure).

Answer (score 2):

using Azure, one option is using Azure WebJobs and it works with Exe files too (if your program is .exe)

Acceptable file types for scripts or programs to be used in Azure Web Jobs:

- .cmd, .bat, .exe (using windows cmd)
- .ps1 (using powershell)
- .sh (using bash)
- .php (using php)
- .py (using python)
- .js (using node)
- .jar (using java)

For more detail information take a look at this link:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/